# Google Login OAuth 2 in iOS app is slow

Tags: ios, oauth, google-signin, google-oauth

I have a website that runs a google login app that works 100% fine in all browsers. I have an iOS app that simply runs the website in a web view. Everything seems to work fine in the iOS app, except when I click the google login button in the webview, it takes 5-10 minutes for the OAuth to finish.

Has anyone run into anything like this, or have any ideas what I could try?

Comment: Hello jimmy , i have the same problem , do you How to fix it ? thanks

Comment: Hi David, unfortunately not. We are still having the issue, and no one really seems to have any idea why.

Comment: Hi Jimmy ,thank you for your response.